# Generate a download from client side javascript data

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side-scripting

I've this code to generate a download from javascript but I can't/don't know how to make it work on mobile devices.

```
$('#export').on("click", function (e) {
     var Datos = {
        "imagen": "asdfASDF123",
        "puntos": [{"a":"1"}, {"b":"2"}, {"c":"3"}]
    };
    stringy = JSON.stringify(Datos);
    var blob = new Blob([stringy], {
        type: "text/json"
    });
    var uri = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = 'datos.json'; 
    link.href = uri;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    fireEvent(link, "click"); 
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
});
```

Is there something bad in this code? or is there another method to generate a download from javascript that works on mobile devices?

Comment: What error is the mobile device showing? You need to figure out the line where the code is error-ing out.

Comment: No error on console using chrome remote debugging. It seems like click event is not triggered.

Comment: I mean $('#export').on("click" does not trigger... but I have others on("click" which are working... weird...